# Get all size of values in a HashMap<String,List<String,String>>

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

In my HashMap < String,List< String,String>> I saved keys (Name of a building) and values (Id´s from devices in this building).
I just want to get the size of values from each keys in my HashMap but the only size I get is from the first Key,Value pair...Here´s my code

```
    Map<String, List<String>> moduleNamesWithAllParameters = new       
    HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> moduleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator it;
    int start = 0, end = 0, mapKeys = 0;

    parameters.add("kExmWoEM2HpMA4CT");
    parameters.add("ILm1nApv06lDtqva");
    parameters.add("gu00xoO5WPTv0SEr");
    parameters.add("kX4FIg6c3C10msex");
    parameters.add("xUcA4Y5rvqxlg8ju");
    parameters.add("TYjydK6AyY7vwYSo");
    parameters.add("#");
    parameters.add("IDvHK1vXMiDEPxad");
    parameters.add("ja0D3LH8ML0mQwZ0");
    parameters.add("#");
    parameters.add("tKgYRVvguvl3ByRc");
    parameters.add("I95sFdAOoUTHjO7Y");

    moduleNames.add("Building 1");
    moduleNames.add("Building 2");
    moduleNames.add("Building 3");

    it = parameters.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleNames.size(); i++) {
        do {
            end++;
        } while (it.hasNext() && !(it.next().equals("#")));
        moduleNamesWithAllParameters.put(moduleNames.get(i), parameters.subList(start, end - 1));
        start = end;
    }

    for (String key : moduleNamesWithAllParameters.keySet())
        System.out.println(key + " = " + moduleNamesWithAllParameters.get(key));

    Entry<String, List<String>> entry;
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleNames.size(); i++) {
        entry = moduleNamesWithAllParameters.entrySet().iterator().next();
        mapKeys = entry.getValue().size();
        System.out.println(mapKeys);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a handful of good answers here, don't forget to vote/accept the best one -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the answers mentioned above, if you want to get sum of all the values of the map, then you can do something like this:

```
moduleNamesWithAllParameters.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
entry = moduleNamesWithAllParameters.entrySet().iterator().next();
```

Is constantly creating a new iterator over the entry set of the map and returning the first entry. So you will only ever see the first entry.

You can change the loop to loop over all entries like this:

```
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : moduleNamesWithAllParameters.entrySet()) {
    mapKeys = entry.getValue().size();
    System.out.println(mapKeys);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java8 or later:

```
moduleNamesWithAllParameters.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().size());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probleam is happend in this line:

`entry = moduleNamesWithAllParameters.entrySet().iterator().next();`

`entrySet().iterator()` is a new object each time it loops.

So you map size only is the first size.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last loop with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < moduleNames.size(); i++) {

    mapKeys = moduleNamesWithAllParameters.get(moduleNames.get(i)).size();
    System.out.println(mapKeys);
}
```

Or a bit neater:

```
for(String key : moduleNamesWithAllParameters.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(moduleNamesWithAllParameters.get(key).size());
}
```

Or even neater (Java 8+):

```
moduleNamesWithAllParameters.stream().forEach(entry ->
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().getSize())
);
```

Or loop using `valueSet` (since you don't actually use the key):

```
for(List<String> value : moduleNamesWithAllParameters.valueSet()) {
    System.out.println(value.size());
}
```

Or if you so fancy (Java 8+):

```
moduleNamesWithAllParameters.valueSet().stream().map(List::size).forEach(System.out::println);
```